# i am writing a machine driver for my board and i am confused where to put the gpio stuff?

Tags: linux-kernel, raspberry-pi, linux-device-driver, gpio

I am re-writing the machine driver for the raspberry pi with wolfson card.

i am getting confusion where to put the clock and gpio stufff in the machine driver.

Can anyone give suggestion about this.

Where we wrote the things like gpio and the clocking stuff in machine driver

Comment: It's not really clear the question

Comment: in the machine driver of the raspberry pi, we intially put all the stuff like gpio initializing and clock initializing and now we want to move the initializations of the clock and gpios to other place, but i dont know where to move.